# Entity framework and order by on many-many table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var articles = (from a in context.Articles
                                    where a.Id != articleId
                                    orderby a.Categories ??Name?? ascending
                                    select a).ToList();
```

a.Categories is table (connected with many-many relation)

```
public EntityCollection<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Category>("AsoModel.CategoryArticle", "Category");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Category>("AsoModel.CategoryArticle", "Category", value);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i use ascending by Name on that Category table.

example:

Article name: Football and this article is in category Sport and News. So two tables are conected by many-many relationship. Now i want to order this article by category name and News is first, Sport is second...

Comment: This question is irrational, how to sort articles base on categories names?! explain your question with some example.

Comment: If you have multiple categories, on which one do you want to sort? I don't suppose that all category names for an article are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var articles = context.Articles.Where(a=>a.Id != articleId)
.OrderBy(p=>p.Categories.OrderBy(q=>q.Name).FirstOrDefault().Name).ToList();
```